# Change return-fields in read method django-piston

Tags: python, django, api, python-imaging-library, django-piston

i'm using django-piston to create my api. I need to know if possible to change the return-fields according to a parameter. I'm trying to return a thumbnail field, but i need to have the option to pass the sizes of the thumbnail via URL.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you clarify specifically what you want to change / provide examples of the expected output for a given input? It sounds like you want to add or remove items from YourHandler.fields, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Having just puzzled out something similar, I believe I can help point you in the right direction.

The basic thing to realize is that *piston does not care what you're returning*. For my use case, I wanted to return sub-resources. So, if I had:

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "baz": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 23}],
}
```

I could request just the `baz` object, and get:

```
{
    "baz": [{"id": 1}, {"id": 23}],
}
```

At first I tried dynamically changing the `fields` or `excludes` for the handler, but that ***was completely the wrong approach***. Once I realized that piston doesn't care at all, I simply did this:

```
 if attrib is not None:
     if hasattr(binder, attrib):
         return getattr(binder, attrib)

     else:
         return rc.BAD_REQUEST
```

Which works great. One caveat: *`fields` or `excludes` applies to the object you return.* It caught me off-guard when I tried to return an sub-resource and I wasn't getting all the fields. So, **please** check that if you run into problems.

For your case, specifically, I would think you could easily generate your thumbnail to the size requested, and then build a meta object to return:

```
meta = dict()
meta['thumbnail' = generateThumbnail(width, height)
meta['other_field'] = base.other_field

return meta
```

See if that works for you.